# Не открываеться сайт. Python(Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x

```
option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled',False)


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:/driver/geckodriver.exe',options=option)
browser.get('https://customers.katzd.co.il/run/')
```

Сайт блокирует подлючение через селениум.Можно как-то обойти?
Возможно использовать хром или же мозилу

Comment: Ну, проставьте какие-то параметры браузера по максимуму - UserAgent и прочие, посмотрите где-нибудь, тут были где-то варианты.

Comment: Не обязательно было удалять прошлый вопрос, можно было его просто отредактировать - под вопросом есть кнопка "править"